# Why is seq(x) so much slower than 1:length(x)?

Tags: r

I recently answered a question pertaining to `for` loops. Upon testing my code's speed, I noticed that the use of `seq()` as opposed to `:` in the `for` loop slowed the speed down considerably.

Have a look at this very simple example. The only difference between `f1()` and `f2()` is a change in the `for` loop sequence, yet `f1()` is over twice as fast as `f2()`.

```
f1 <- function() {
    x <- 1:5; y <- numeric(length(x))
    for(i in 1:length(x)) y[i] <- x[i]^2
    y
}

f2 <- function() {
    x <- 1:5; y <- numeric(length(x))
    for(i in seq(x)) y[i] <- x[i]^2
    y
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min      lq  median     uq    max neval
#  f1() 10.529 11.5415 12.1465 12.617 33.893   100
#  f2() 25.052 25.5905 26.0385 28.759 78.553   100
```

Why is `seq(x)` so much slower in a `for` loop than `1:length(x)` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`seq` is a generic S3 method, so probably some time is lost dispatching.
`seq.default` is almost 100 lines long!

You're probably already aware of `seq_along`, which calls a `.Primitive` directly and is bit better than `1:length(x)` and the best method I have found for long loops:

```
f3 <- function(){
      x <- 1:5; y <- numeric(length(x))
      for(i in seq_along(x)) y[i] <- x[i]^2
      y
  }
>  microbenchmark(f1(), f3())
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
 f1() 27.095 27.916 28.327 29.148 89.495   100
 f3() 26.684 27.505 27.916 28.327 36.538   100
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `seq_len` you get nearly the same time as the `:` operator:

```
f3 <- function(){
  x <- 1:5; y <- numeric(length(x))
  for(i in seq_len(length(x))) y[i] <- x[i]^2
  y
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(),f3())

Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq  median     uq    max neval
 f1()  9.988 10.6855 10.9650 11.245 50.704   100
 f2() 23.257 23.7465 24.0605 24.445 88.140   100
 f3() 10.127 10.5460 10.7555 11.175 18.857   100
```

Internally `seq` is doing many verifications before calling `:` or `seq_len`.

Answer (score 3):

A more specific reason why it's slower:

`seq(x)` will call `seq.default`*, and `seq.default` calls `1L:x`!!

From `seq.default`:

```
if ((One <- nargs() == 1L) && !missing(from)) {
    lf <- length(from)
    return(if (mode(from) == "numeric" && lf == 1L) {
        #checks validity -- more slow-down
        if (!is.finite(from)) stop("'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite")
        #boom! under the hood, seq.default is doing 1:N
        1L:from
    #looks like it defaults to seq_along if length(from) > 1?
    } else if (lf) 1L:lf else integer())
}
```

*Unless, of course, `x` is `Date` or `POSIXt`, or you have another library loaded that has a `seq` method...